# how we can have ToolkitScriptManager & ScriptManager both in master page

Tags: asp.net

before i was using ScriptManager in the master page. and when i was running main page i had not any problem.

now i have decided to add combo box to main page , so i should add ToolkitScriptManager to the master page.

because of error , i removed ScriptManager of the master page but now my main page has completely post back and slow, how i can have both of them in the master page without error.

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjectDocument" runat="server" Height="16px" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
     Width="212px" onselectedindexchanged="ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged"
    AutoPostBack="True" onload="ddlProjectDocument_Load"
    style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace" >

    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">(select a value)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />

<ajaxtoolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" onload="ComboBox1_Load"
     AutoCompleteMode="Suggest"
     style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace" >

</ajaxtoolkit:ComboBox>

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlProjectDocument"  />


</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

master page:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterAdmin.master.cs" Inherits="MasterAdmin" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        width: 40%;
        font-size:large;
    }
</style>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   </head>
  <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager>
```

Answer (score 3):

1.Use `<asp:toolkitscriptmanager>` in master page instead of `<scriptmanager>`.

2.Remove `<asp:toolkitscriptmanager>` from your content pages as only **`one script manager`** can exist at an instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have done both items but it seems <ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager> does not work like <scriptmanager> , because i have problem of completely post back on the content page.just difference is i have used in master page <ajaxtoolkit:toolkitscriptmanager> instead of <asp:toolkitscriptmanager>, i do not know this is problem or no?